# object of type List<T1,T2,T3> in C# where T is a class. Is this possible?

Tags: c#, list

I am writing a query in SQL to get data from more than 3 tables. These tables have different information say Student Table's data is mapped with Student Class, Address Table data with Address Class and Group table data in Group class. I want to comp=bile all the data into one and sent it to my UI. This data from DB will be join result of all ,y tables and I need to save it in an object like List. Is there any other way to do so if this isn't possible? I cannot use LINQ here as there is some restriction with the Project Architecture.

Comment: It is really unclear what you want to do. You ned to start by defining what your UI needs, and writing a clean model for that. You would commonly refer to that as `DTO`. you would then select the necessary data from wherever (including your 3 tables) and hydrate the model you've defined.

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing to what I believe you are asking is "list of [tuples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx)" - `List<Tuple<T1,T2,T3>>`.

Most likely it is better to create custom class containing properties for each of these elements and then store them in a list like:

```
  class StudentInfo
  {
      public Student { get;set; }
      public Address { get;set; }
      public Group { get;set; }
  }
```

Such data-only class frequently called "Data Transfer Object" (DTO).

Comment: I want the Data to be shown as {"Student Name",ID,"Address1","Address2","Group Red"}. The list I am sending is to be bind in XLSX worksheet of AngularJS 4. It doesnt understand dot operators. If anyone knows to bind the same it would be a great help.

Comment: @VarshaTiwari there is absolutely no way to figure out that from the way question asked... (and it feels too broad for SO)

Comment: I want to bind 'StudentInfo.Student.Id' object to XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(StudentInfo) in angularJS4 which returns [Object].[Object].[Object] in this case when I generate the excel.I am new to angular if someone could help me with the binding of this C# object returned from my API which is sent as json to UI where it is been bindto Excel of AngularJS.If someone can provide a link or a sample code in Git or jsfiddle it would be a great help